# Dynamic HTML attributes with ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can I add HTML attributes dynamically through `ng-repeat`?

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="thing in things" {{thing.ghosted||'disabled'}}>
        {{thing.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this, it'd be good to use a directive.

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-disabled="thing.ghosted">
        {{thing.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 I knew but didn't understand `{{thing.ghosted||'disabled'}}` meaning